# Is the Oracle ORDS Oauth2 Rest service protected by cross origins (CORS)?

Tags: angular, oracle, oauth-2.0, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I am using oracle apex for a school project and am using Angular as front end.

Whenever I request the authentication token by passing oauth client_id and client_secret, I get an error in Angular.

When this is done in Postman however. This works perfectly as seen below:
[image: postman request and response showing how Authorization: Basic base64(client_id:client_recret) and content type: application/x-www.form-unlencoded gives a response with token, expires_in and token_type]

The yellow line is the base64 encoded 'client_id':client_secret' combination.
 [image: shows the body in postman of the previous request as 'grant_type:client_credentaials']

However, when the same HTTP request is sent through angular, as shown:

```
getToken() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders(      
      {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("pTgmbDsLzXokh5-K__t5sw.." + ':' + "ww2DnvIVV9siqdcE92oo9g.."),
    });

    let options = { headers: headers };
    return this.http.post(this.urlLogin, "grant_type=client_credentials", options);
}
```

The following error is received on the console:
[image: CORS policy error followed by dailed to load error]

In the network tab, I get 2 failed entries for the same post request:
[image: 2 entries in chrome's network pane, both in red. one of failed network error, another with 401 error]

In the first one, the following is shown in HTTP headers
 [image: HTTP request details from chrome]

In the second one (with the 401 response), the following is seen
 [image: HTTP error with (401) error code]
[image: above HTTP error continued]

I have only sent one HTTP POST request as shown in the above screenshot. Why is the HTTP request being sent twice?

What seems to be the problem here?

Is the oauth API protected by cross origin?

Comment: using a proxy configuration in angular may resolve your issue .see https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d

Answer (score 0):

The reason HTTP request being sent twice is one for sending request and other for the response.
            Since you are running the angular app in localhost but consuming the API service from non local (apex..) 
            It results in CORS issue.To avoid either

```
        1)run service locally 
        2)disable CORS
```

Comment: that's wrong, the first request used the method option, and it's called 
 `preflight` means `A preflight request is a small request sent by the browser before the actual request. It contains information like which HTTP method is used and if any custom HTTP headers are present. The preflight gives the server a chance to examine what the actual request will look like before it's made.
`